# Accidentally deleted /tmp/systemd-private-015eb2a30-apache2.service-9h6i

Tags: systemd, apache2, tmp, systempath

I accidentally deleted `systemd-private-015eb2e9f67b4eef862c68e99fe0ba30-apache2.service-9h6i08` from my /tmp folder:

```
sudo rm -R /tmp/systemd-private-015eb2e9f67b4eef862c68e99fe0ba30-apache2.service-9h6i08
```

and didn't mean for it not to disappear permanently. I was sure it would get displayed back again. This makes my code break since it's not finding the secured folder to write files to it.

How do I return the file back again?

I tried creating the directory again - with only root permissions and ownership - but this doesn't work.

Comment: Nothing in /tmp should be crucial to a system, as it's explicitly meant to be emptied after a reboot. Restarting the service should fix it.

Comment: It may not be crucial to the system - but it surely shouldn't be expected that you can remove files created by running processes without adversely affecting them? :)

Comment: "didn't mean for it not to disappear permanently" huh? Too many negatives there.

Comment: @NiallLitchfield it is intended by design that deleting any files in `/tmp` shall not affect any processes. If a process is affected by deleting a tmpfile, its a badly programmed process. A process should hold a filepointer opened to its tmpfile in `/tmp` to block any attempts of third party processes or should make sure that no other process than a root process is able to interact with its tmpfile in a destructive way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Restarting Apache should recreate it (with a slightly different name).

Assuming Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```